# WP e-commerce sales-view

Tags: plugins, options, e-commerce

I'm helping a client out who's running Wordpress E-commerce 3.8.3 on WP 3.2.1

In the "sales" view, (where it shows all orders), you can see

ID Date/Time Name Amount Details Status (Delete) and Track-ID

My client wants to view the orderers e-mail and phone too. There are fields for this in the checkout, and the confirmation emails do include this information. But how can I make them show in the Sales-view too? WP E-commerce isn't my strongest side.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

not really php solution, but that's how I solved this problem.
I deactivated phone and email fields from Store Settings -> Chekout and created custom ones. so now when I go to orders it displays in like

Additional Checkout Fields

Phone:

Email: